# how to avoid reaching max size of varchar2 in concat with update

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle. when updating a table i am using

```
update my_table set column_name =concat(" ' ", column_name, "viewed by xxxx") 
where item_value=2.
```

this value is being appended whenever some one is viewing...
   Now my question is  How to avoid max size of varchar(2) and set if it is just 50 characters lesser than its size. I am using this in servlet

My requirement is ..If some user views the item_value of 2, his userid is to be entered in my_table by concatinating the existing values in column_name where item_value=2, in one word I dont want to loose the earlier data in field when updating and to avoid reaching the max size of the field which is varchar2(900).

If the field reaches max size then the existing data will be ovewritten by the new data else it will be a concatination to existing data.

Comment: The substr() function will restrict the number of characters, but it's not clear what you want to do if the result of your concat function is more than 50 characters.

Comment: I don't know enought about your case but sometime, strings like "viewed by " are not stored in the database but just added in the UI. and xxxx would be an ID to a person table.

Comment: Maybe another option could be to INSERT to some log table instead? This adds also info how application was used, actions sequence etc

Answer (score 2):

Just use SUBSTR:

```
update my_table set column_name
    = SUBSTR(' '' ' || column_name || 'viewed by xxxx')
            , 1, 900)
where item_value=2
```

P.S. concat can only take 2 arguments - I've converted your code to use the simpler || concatenation operator instead.

P.P.S. string literals in Oracle are delimited by `'` not `"`

Comment: This will work until the parameter for substr exceeds SQL internal limit of 4000 Chars. Best option is to create a PL/SQL procedure with 3 parameters. Then concat strings in the procedure. PL/SQL's internal limit for VARCHAR2s is 32KB. Then return result of PL/SQL's substr not the SQL's one

Comment: @Ivan, that'd be true but in this case we know that `column_name` will never be >900 characters, so this will always fit within 4000 characters.

Comment: in this case what happens if the existing string value exceeds 900, will it be set with new value or the update will fail?...

Comment: @raja, `column_name` has a maximum size of 900 - it *cannot* exceed that. It is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a stored procedure that you will call to update that field. It will check what the new size will be after the update, and if it is too large then perform whatever action you need to (ie. add to archive table, trim off existing data, etc.).